# Best practice for database design with images and thumbnails with external storage in S3?

Tags: database, image, amazon-s3

First: Im persisting images in amazon s3.

So the URL root for my images are:
https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/

My design tables and relationships:

table **document**

```
id     file_name
1      my_document
```

table **images**

```
id document_id  missing_column??
1     1
2     1
```

table **images_sizes**

```
id    images_id     image_size          file_name        file_extension
1         1          800                output1               .png
2         2          800                output2               .png
3         1          200                output1               .png
4         2          200                output2               .png
```

then to build the url to get a image will be
https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/document_id/image_size/file_name+file_extension

But i dont know if i am on the right way. What are the drawback modeling this way? Do you suggest me another way? The images table miss a column to differ registers. I dont know exactly what do do.

Comment: you are on the right way. personally, I would keep file name along with extension, but if you want it to be like that, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have just 1 table?

```
|Image 
----------------------------------------------------------
id | image_size(if you need to know size) | url(varchar)
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Filename can be tricky. You might have 2 images with same filename. Use an id as the key name in S3. If you use the id, you can get rid of 'url' column above and follow the convention like

```
https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/id.jpeg
```

You also don't need image_size in the URL and table, if it's a fixed size.
If you're saving a set of standard sizes, you can follow a convention like youtube does -

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```